# Which file to deploy after .sln msbuild is successful

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-devops, sln-file

I am trying to deploy a web application in AWS/AZure using VSTS for that i have .sln soultion file to build. MS build is successful but it does not generate any artifacts even if it does i am not able to find it. I Don't know which file to deploy after successful build . Here are the logs generated by the build:

> 2018-02-23T06:14:56.6241643Z ##[section]Starting: Build solution **/*.sln
>   2018-02-23T06:14:56.6245894Z ==============================================================================
>   2018-02-23T06:14:56.6246019Z Task         : MSBuild
>   2018-02-23T06:14:56.6246112Z Description  : Build with MSBuild
>   2018-02-23T06:14:56.6246202Z Version      : 1.120.0
>   2018-02-23T06:14:56.6246308Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2018-02-23T06:14:56.6246426Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613724)
>   2018-02-23T06:14:56.6246538Z ==============================================================================
>   2018-02-23T06:15:01.0364172Z ##[command]"D:\a_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,16.0) -latest -format json
>   2018-02-23T06:15:02.2426059Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\Laan.SolutionConverter.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="D:\a\1\a\" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_eb74fc1a-1d38-4e9e-ba62-24d0d644d78d_build_1_52"
>   2018-02-23T06:15:02.3412576Z Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
>   2018-02-23T06:15:02.3840313Z Build started 2/23/2018 6:15:02 AM.
>   2018-02-23T06:15:03.0801650Z Project "D:\a\1\s\Laan.SolutionConverter.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
>   2018-02-23T06:15:03.0810648Z ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
>   2018-02-23T06:15:03.0810789Z   Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
>   2018-02-23T06:15:03.3437875Z Project "D:\a\1\s\Laan.SolutionConverter.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\Laan.SolutionConverter\Laan.SolutionConverter.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
>   2018-02-23T06:15:03.3438402Z RestorePackages:
>   2018-02-23T06:15:03.3438811Z   "D:\a\1\s.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "D:\a\1\s\Laan.SolutionConverter\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\a\1\s\ "
>   2018-02-23T06:15:06.5368000Z   Restoring NuGet packages...
>   2018-02-23T06:15:06.5368544Z   To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
>   2018-02-23T06:15:06.9195161Z   All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
>   2018-02-23T06:15:06.9965845Z PrepareForBuild:
>   2018-02-23T06:15:06.9966207Z   Creating directory "bin\Debug\".
>   2018-02-23T06:15:06.9970357Z   Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
>   2018-02-23T06:15:08.7989740Z CoreCompile:
>   2018-02-23T06:15:08.7990805Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:D:\a\1\s\packages\CommandLineParser.1.9.71\lib\net45\CommandLine.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\Laan.SolutionConverter.exe /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:exe /utf8output SlnToXmlConverter.cs Core\BracketStructure.cs Core\CandidateDefinition.cs Core\CustomParser.cs Core\CustomTokenizer.cs Core\ITokenizer.cs Core\Position.cs Documents\GlobalSection.cs Documents\Project.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Core\RegexTokenizer.cs Core\SlnTokenizer.cs Documents\SolutionDocument.cs Parsers\SolutionParser.cs Core\SyntaxException.cs Core\Token.cs Core\TokenDefinition.cs Core\TokenType.cs Utils\XmlExtensions.cs XmlToSlnConverter.cs Xml\NameValueItem.cs Xml\NameValue.cs Xml\SolutionFolder.cs Xml\SolutionItem.cs Xml\SolutionProject.cs Xml\Solution.cs "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>   2018-02-23T06:15:09.3845371Z   Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0206869Z _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0207148Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\CommandLineParser.1.9.71\lib\net45\CommandLine.dll" to "bin\Debug\CommandLine.dll".
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0214491Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\CommandLineParser.1.9.71\lib\net45\CommandLine.xml" to "bin\Debug\CommandLine.xml".
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0222636Z   Creating "D:\a\1\s\Laan.SolutionConverter\obj\Debug\Laan.SolutionConverter.csproj.CopyComplete" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0246034Z CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0246192Z   Copying file from "obj\Debug\Laan.SolutionConverter.exe" to "bin\Debug\Laan.SolutionConverter.exe".
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0250947Z   Laan.SolutionConverter -> D:\a\1\s\Laan.SolutionConverter\bin\Debug\Laan.SolutionConverter.exe
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0253057Z   Copying file from "obj\Debug\Laan.SolutionConverter.pdb" to "bin\Debug\Laan.SolutionConverter.pdb".
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0345637Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\Laan.SolutionConverter\Laan.SolutionConverter.csproj" (default targets).
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0355240Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\Laan.SolutionConverter.sln" (default targets).
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0372793Z 
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0372977Z Build succeeded.
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0375964Z     0 Warning(s)
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0376186Z     0 Error(s)
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0918805Z 
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.0919153Z Time Elapsed 00:00:22.65
>   2018-02-23T06:15:25.1275235Z ##[section]Finishing: Build solution **/*.sln

Can Anyone tell which file should i choose to deploy after reading these logs?

Comment: Could you provide screenshot of Build pipeline [Build task]?

Comment: Can you share a sample project on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log:

> `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
>   /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
>   /p:PackageLocation="D:\a\1\a\"`

So, it should generate the web deployment package to artifact folder (D:\a\1\a) if it is a web application, you can add a `Publish Build Artifacts` task to publish these files (Path to publish: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`)

Comment: I tried this..but it says "[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'arti'." what does that mean? It's an web application it should definitely generate some artifacts to be deployed later.

Comment: @meenakshiarya Is it a web application or web site?